field lines of a $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ function (ellipses)
i have the following exercise:
Characterize the field lines of the following vector field $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2:$
$g(x,y)=(\frac{-y}{a^2}, \frac{x}{b^2}) $ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  \{0\}$
Show that the field lines form ellipses.

ellipses would mean the fulfill $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y}{b^2}=1$ ... but how can i show that. And how do I "characterize" field lines

@JeanMarie Yes the field lines are ellipses. But for exactly that reason the field $g$ is not conservative. Take $a=b=1$ and integrate $g$ around the unit circle (closed loop). That integral is $2\pi,.$

@Kurt G.  You are perfectly right, thanks.  I was mixing field lines and isopotential lines.
